# how to implement buffer management for printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I believe my issue stems from the `printf` print buffer, but I know too little about C or buffers to know how to handle this.  I have a simple program written and it just prints a bunch of text (chars/strings) based on some `if`/`else` statements depending on the file that is input.  If I call it from a Unix shell like so:

```
gcc -o myProgram myProgram.c
./myProgram fileName
```

It will print out correctly for only the first run.  If i reiterate these steps and once again run the program, it prints out a bunch of "bash" commands in between the output `printf`s.  Is there an easy way to debug or fix this issue?  I'm very new to C, if you couldn't tell, and I'm using this as part of a school assignment so I am trying to actually figure this out and understand this concept, such that I can then apply it back into my actual program assignment.

EDIT: This is a make-shift example to try to demo my issue
Note: The file inputted just contains text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S{
    char word[30];
}s;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    void print(struct S *s);
    int i; 
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, f);
    print(&s);
    fclose(f);
}

void print(struct S *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("Word: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        if(s->word[i] != '\0')
        {
            printf("%c", s->word[i]);
        }       
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: And you think we can help you without looking at your code?

Comment: The code is very length, but I can try to come up with a smaller sample.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma, Yes, smaller is better as long as it reproduces your error.

Comment: I omitted most the junk.  This should still re-create my error when called multiple times.

Comment: "Should recreate" or "does recreate"? First step in debugging is reproducing the problem!

Comment: It does indeed cause me the same issue if I modify my code to match this one and run it.  (I just edited my original code with more generic names and cut out some loops.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test this :

Add the following line at the first line in the main() :

```
setbuf( stdout , NULL );
```

The outputs of a program are stored in a buffer and when you call printf they are extracted. the setbuf() method is used for handling that buffer. when You add setbuf(stdout , NULL), this tells the buffer that don't store the outputs and directly send outputs of the program into the stdout.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry if my example made it hard to understand.  This fixed my issue.  If you don't mind, you would also explain what my issue is and why this is fixing it?! :)

Comment: Updated my answer MrHappyAsthma